# Lost in Space Episode - Alternative Ending?

Tags: lost-in-space, lost-in-space-1965

I recently watched the *Lost in Space* episode "Welcome, Stranger", but found the ending different from what I remembered.

As I recalled it, Professor Robinson and Don went out looking for Will and Penny (who had run away to avoid being sent back to Earth), but saw the visiting spaceship taking off without them, whereupon they called to the children to come out, as "It doesn't makes any difference now".

However, the version I just saw on tv doesn't include this, merely showing the children being reunited with the adults, who had apparently (it wasn't made clear) just changed their minds about sending the kids away. Does anyone know if the ending could have been changed or is my memory at fault?

Comment: One of the networks that has rights to a lot of these old, old shows is notorious for re-editing them to fit in more advertising.  Might they have just deleted the spaceship takeoff scene?

Comment: Yes. Rather what I suspected. It's the sort of behaviour that really gets on my wick.

Comment: Internet Movie Database does list two alternative bits of trivia for endings : https://imdb.com/title/tt0058824/alternateversions?ref_=m_tt_trv_alt